# T-sql View one column to multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to script a view. The Catch is I need to uses values from one column of the original table and display them in multiple columns in my view. Does anyone have a sample script I can follow? For example I have a table with a column that has 20 different features. I need to have 20 different columns in the view just for the features part. The features column will have data like "Leather Seats" "1/2 Bathroom"

Thank you again[image: Source Data table and View]

Comment: This sounds like a `PIVOT`. Please include some sample data and your desired results so we can help further. You can use a site [like this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to help format a table nicely for pasting here. Just indent each line with 4 spaces or use the code formatting button at the top so it's monospaced and properly highlighted as code after pasting.

Comment: Can you provide any sample data?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the mapping.

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Sample input???  Sample output???

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the DDL or DML, and I don't have time to do it for you, I'll give you a 'generic' solution.

```
declare @survey table (Respondent int identity(1,1), Q1 int, Q2 int, Q3 int, Q4 int, Q5 int)
declare @questions table (PK_quID int identity(1,1), quName varchar(255))
declare @answers table (PK_anID int identity(1,1), anName varchar(255))

insert into @questions values ('Do you have a drivers license?')
insert into @questions values ('What best describes your current employment conditions?')
insert into @questions values ('Do you have hair?')
insert into @questions values ('What kind of vehicle do you drive?')
insert into @questions values ('What state are you from?')
insert into @answers values ('yes')
insert into @answers values ('no')
insert into @answers values ('working')
insert into @answers values ('not working')
insert into @answers values ('car')
insert into @answers values ('truck')
insert into @answers values ('suv')
insert into @answers values ('MO')
insert into @answers values ('IL')
insert into @answers values ('TN')
insert into @survey values (1,3,1,5,8)
insert into @survey values (2,4,1,6,8)
insert into @survey values (1,4,1,7,9)
insert into @survey values (2,3,2,6,9)
insert into @survey values (1,3,1,5,10)



select
    s.*,
    qu.*,
    an.*
from
(
    select 
        Respondent,
        right(Q,1) as Q, 
        A 
    from @survey
    unpivot
    (
        A for Q in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5)
    ) as u
) s
    left outer join @questions qu
        on s.Q=qu.PK_quID
    left outer join @answers an
        on s.a = an.PK_anID
```

Also...

```
declare @responses table (Respondent int, FK_quID int, FK_anID int)

insert into @responses
(
    Respondent,
    FK_quID,
    FK_anID
)
select 
    Respondent,
    right(Q,1) as Q, 
    A 
from @survey
unpivot
(
    A for Q in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5)
) as u
```

Finally...

```
select
*
from
(
    select
        Respondent,
        quName,
        anName
    from @responses r
        inner join @questions q
            on r.FK_quID=q.PK_quID
        inner join @answers a
            on r.FK_anID=a.PK_anID
) a
pivot
(
    count(a.Respondent)
    for anName in 
        (
            [yes],
            [no],
            [working],
            [not working],
            [car],
            [truck],
            [suv],
            [MO],
            [IL],
            [TN]
        )
) as pvt
```

[image]

See the links below for more info.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/how-to-unpivot-and-pivot/

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/understanding-sql-server-2000-pivot/